# Codeigniter: uploading from the form is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am uploading images to "images" directory and some info to my database in codeigniter. But when I click to submit button after completing form, It doesn't do anything.  It simply just refreshes. If someone could please look over this code, and tell me why it's not working. Thank you in advance. 
Here my controller code:

```
<?php       public function create()
    {

        if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $title['title'] = 'Add News';
            $this->load->view('templates/navbar', $title);
            $this->load->view('News/create');

        }
        else
        {
            // image1
            $ImageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $imageSize= $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $imageSource = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "images/$ImageName");
            $this->create_thumb($ImageName);
            $this->compress($ImageName, $imageSize, "images/$ImageName");

            // image2
            if ($this->input->post('image2')){
            $ImageName2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
            $imageSize2= $_FILES['image2']['size'];
            $imageSource2 = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name']; 
            $this->compress($ImageName2, $imageSize2, $imageSource2);
            }
            // image3
            if ($this->input->post('image3')){
            $ImageName3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
            $imageSize3= $_FILES['image3']['size'];
            $imageSource3 = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name']; 
            $this->compress($ImageName3, $imageSize3, $imageSource3);
            }
            // image4
            if ($this->input->post('image4')){
            $ImageName4 = $_FILES['image4']['name'];
            $imageSize4= $_FILES['image4']['size'];
            $imageSource4 = $_FILES['image4']['tmp_name']; 
            $this->compress($ImageName4, $imageSize4, $imageSource4);
            }

            $this->news_model->set_news();
            $this->load->view('News/success');
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Here my view code:

```
       <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/news/create/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Сарлавха:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Сарлавха">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Автомобил тури:</label>
                                            <select name="category" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="yuk">Юк</option>
                                                    <option value="kichik">Кичик тижорат</option>       
                                                    <option value="yengil">Енгил</option>
                                                    <option value="maxsus">Махсус техника</option>
                                                    <option value="tyagach">Тягач</option>
                                                    <option value="prisep">Прицеп</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Нархи:</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Нархи">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Исми ва шарифи:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Исми ва шарифи">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Телефон рақам:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="telno" class="form-control" value="+998" placeholder="Телефон рақам">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Жойи:</label>
                                            <select name="location" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="Қорақалпоғистон Республикаси">Қорақалпоғистон Республикаси</option>
                                                    <option value="Бухоро вилояти">Бухоро вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Жиззах вилояти">Жиззах вилояти</option>      
                                                    <option value="Қашқадарё вилояти">Қашқадарё вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Навоий вилояти">Навоий вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Наманган вилояти">Наманган вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Сурхондарё вилояти">Сурхондарё вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Сирдарё вилояти">Сирдарё вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Тошкент вилояти">Тошкент вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Фарғона вилояти">Фарғона вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Хоразм вилояти">Хоразм вилояти</option>
                                                    <option value="Тошкент шаҳар">Тошкент шаҳар</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Қўшимча маълумот:</label>
                                            <textarea rows="5" name="info" class="form-control" placeholder="Қўшимча маълумот" ></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Асосий расмни танланг:</label>
                                            <input type="file" name='image' class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Қўшимча расмни танланг:</label>
                                            <input type="file" name='image2' class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Қўшимча расмни танланг:</label>
                                            <input type="file" name='image3' class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Қўшимча расмни танланг:</label>
                                            <input type="file" name='image4' class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" name="submit" value="submit">Юклаш</button>
                                <div class="clearfix" ></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Files have nothing to do with the $_POST array. You would need to iterate over the $_FILES array.

Comment: check page roytuts.com/codeigniter-multiple-files-upload/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post the submit, than you have to use `<input />` instead of `<button />` in your view file.

But there is a better way to check, if something posted:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // do something if NOT posted
}
else
{
   // do something if posted
}
```

change to:

```
if ($this->input->post())
{
    // do something if posted
}
else
{
   // do something if NOT!! posted
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still it is not working

Comment: Then try to debug it. Add this to your view: `<?php print "<pre>"; print_r($this->input->post()); print "</pre>"; ?>` This will show you, if you post anything. I recommend you to use the CodeIgniter's form helper for starting and closing tag: `<?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url("index.php/news/create/"), array("id" => "form_id"));` for starting tag, and `<?php echo form_close(); ?>` for closing tag.

Comment: To use the form helper, first you need to load it from your controller: `$this->load->helper("form");`

Comment: I seperated view and upload code in two methods. Then tried to upload but I realized that it posts nothing. What is wrong with code, I can't understand

Comment: And I can't help you if you don't debug it.